# how do i filter out lists of strings that dont match the desired criteria?

Tags: python

i have a few tuples containing strings and i want to remove some of the tuples that have 3 or more of the same elements in it. so i need to check if any of the tuples have 3 or more 'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D' inside them.
 how do i go about it? thanks

```
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A') <--remove because it has more than 3 'A's in it
('A', 'A', 'A', 'B') <--remove because it has 3 'A's in it
('B', 'B', 'B', 'B') <--remove because it has more than 3 'B's in it
('B', 'B', 'B', 'C') <--remove because it has 3 'B's in it
('A', 'A', 'B', 'A') <--remove because it has 3 'A's in it
('A', 'A', 'B', 'B') <--this is ok
('A', 'A', 'B', 'C') <--this is ok
('A', 'A', 'B', 'D') <--this is ok
```

Comment: Is this list of tuples ?

Comment: these are just unnamed tuples generated with 'itertools.product'. i can turn them into list of tuples or anything really

Answer (score 7):

You could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrences of the elements:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
        ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
        ('B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
        ('B', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
        ('A', 'A', 'B', 'A'),
        ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
        ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
        ('A', 'A', 'B', 'D')]


result = [t for t in data if all(value < 3 for value in Counter(t).values())]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'D')]
```

As mentioned by @coldspeed you don't need to test all the values only the largest one:

```
result = [t for t in data if max(Counter(t).values()) < 3]
```

Comment: You don't need to test all the values, just the largest one. Of course, complexity wise it is the same but not as clean.

Comment: @coldspeed Done. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: thank you so much. i tried 'collections.Counter' before but got the syntax wrong. thank you again. u saved me hours of my life :)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This solution involves extra computation, and is less efficient than a `max` on values. Avoid. Refer to comments for an excellent discussion.
You could use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) but use the [`most common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method of the counter to avoid checking all values in the Counter. (EDIT: However, most common requires a heapsort when passed an argument, making it computationally expensive. Thanks for pointing it out in comments.)

```
from collections import Counter

data = [('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
        ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
        ('B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
        ('B', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
        ('A', 'A', 'B', 'A'),
        ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
        ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
        ('A', 'A', 'B', 'D')]


result = [t for t in data if Counter(t).most_common(1)[0][1] < 3]
print(result)
```

Comment: This works and is fine but I believe `most_common` requires a sorting of values, while the others involve a linear scan.

Comment: oh does it? i presumed Counters were already ordered/sorted on creation, but im not a 100% sure.

Comment: Counters use a heap for most_common when n is specified, according to the docs using max is more efficiencient: https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest

Comment: Thanks a ton! @DanielMesejo TIL.

Comment: @DanielMesejo Source code [github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L581](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L581) seems to agree with you.

Comment: i would feel bad deleting this because i find these comments very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to test all the values. You can test only the largest one.

```
result = [i for i in data if max(Counter(i).values()) < 3]
```

**Output**

```
[('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'B', 'D')]
```